# Arquivo corrompe ao tentar copia-lo

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estava tentando copiar um arquivo usando Python, mas o arquivo corrompe...
Vejam o código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
cf = raw_input("File: ")
ds = raw_input("Destino: ")
with open(cf,"rb") as fl:
  for l in fl.read():
    l.rstrip()
with open(ds,"wb") as rw:
  rw.write(l)
print "OK"
```

Comment: Você pode postar o código diretamente na pergunta. O site possui suporte para tal.

Comment: tentei usando a tag code mas ficou bagunçado junto com o resto da pergunta

Comment: Se quiseres por o código na pergunta copie e cole depois tem um botão na edição da pergunta que permite você identar o código...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você fez:

```
with open(cf,"rb") as fl:
  for l in fl.read():
    l.rstrip()
```

Isto é, abre o arquivo para leitura binária, lê **todo o conteúdo** com `fl.read()` e percorre byte a byte efetuando o `rstrip()` em cada byte. Isso já nem faz sentido. Por que percorrer byte a byte do arquivo e, ainda, executar um `rstrip` nele?

E quando você faz:

```
with open(ds,"wb") as rw:
  rw.write(l)
```

Você escreverá **apenas** o último byte do arquivo lido, o que não será um arquivo válido - indicando que está corrompido.

O que você precisa fazer é:

```
with open(cf, 'rb') as entrada:
    with open(ds, 'wb') as saida:
        saida.write(entrada.read())
```

Ou ainda (Python 2.7+):

```
with open(cf, 'rb') as entrada, open(ds, 'wb') as saida:
    saida.write(entrada.read())
```

Mas por que reinventar a roda? Use [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile):

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile(cf, ds)
```

Comment: perfeito, obrigado pela ajuda, usei rstrip() para remover \n, vou usar isso para transferencia em rede, então o shutil não vai me ajudar... obrigado amigo!